# Filter by attribute to show only records with whole numbers

Tags: arcgis-10.0, select-by-attribute

Is there a way to show points that only contain whole numbers in a column (eg. 009, 010, 011 and NOT 9,1; 9,2; 9,3...) in ArcGIS 10?

Comment: Are you doing a select by attribute in ArcMap? if so which version of ArcGIS desktop? You need to give us more details about your data and the software that you are using.

Comment: Is the data in the *km* column stored as a string or a number?

Answer (score 2):

This assumes the *km* column stores numbers, not strings.

Open the table.

Add a new column and name it whatever you want, I'll use *wholenum* in this example.

Right-click the *wholenum* column and choose **Field Calculator**.

Set the Parser to **Python** and put a check in **Show Codeblock**.

Enter this formula in the **Pre-Logic Script Code** field:

```
x = 0 
if [km] MOD 1 = 0 then
x = 1
endif
```

Put *x* in the **km=** field.

Click **OK** to close the Field Calculator.

Set this Definition Query on the layer: `wholenum = 1`.

Now it will only display points with whole number values. You could take similar steps to show every 5 km or 10 km point, by using `MOD 5` and `MOD 10` respectively, to show fewer points at even smaller scales.

Answer (score 2):

I have just had a similar problem and used this work around.

Open the layer properties and select Definition query and use the expression below.

```
KM NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

This will remove all rows with a `.` in the field. As long as the kilometer points aren't whole numbers like 1.0 or 2.0 etc. this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this (if data in the km column is stored as a number):

```
[km] mod 1 = 0
```

The modulo operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another.

Answer (score -1):

If field is numeric, create the following definition query:

```
ROUND("field_name",0) = "field_name"
```